# How to deal with independent variables that seem to follow power law diftribution

Tags: regression, power-law

While I am having a series of regression experiments, I could detect there are 2 independent variables seem to follow power law distribution.(Or, they have too much value of 1) here's a example of them.[image]

Actually I did not think about dealing with this kind of variables. However, I can now think that, maybe, I can improve the modeling by transforming the variables.(for one thing, these variables can be transformed to log scale..)
If there is a ideal condition for independent variable or specific way to satisfy it, please give me some advice.

Comment: OLS regression does not make assumptions about the distribution of the independent variables, it makes assumptions about the error term as measured by the residuals from the model.

That said, an IV as odd as your will cause problems. It looks like you have about 9000  1's and almost none of anything else (although it's hard to tell exactly). If you do have that many 1's, no transformation will fix it, because any transformation will still leave you with a huge pile at one level (e.g. if you take the log, you will have 9000 0's).

Comment: Please tell us more - what are your IVs? What is your DV? Is there a huge pile at a specific value of the IV?

Comment: Thank your for your comments. In my case, DV is Helpfulness and IV is a review's average rating, reviewer's ranking, and total vote for a review(it is used as control variable.) in Amazon. you can refer to this link. [link](http://www.amazon.com/Divergent-Series-Veronica-Roth/product-reviews/0062024035/ref=cm_cr_pr_top_link_10?ie=UTF8&pageNumber=10&showViewpoints=0&sortBy=byRankDescending) Helpfulness is calculated by Helpful Vote / Total Vote for each review. and I'm finding some factors affecting the helpfulness. In this analysis, I thought Total vote should be controlled.

Comment: in a plethora of reviews, there are huge number of reviews that have only one total vote. That's why value of 1 is dominating the value of the variable.

Comment: In my data, for Total vote variable, the number of observations having value of 1 is about 9000. Total number of observations is about 20000

Comment: The DV is originally *count* data, which would cause one strongly to favor a Binomial or Poisson GLM rather than OLS or a Beta regression. Although you do not necessarily have to transform the IV, you should expect to have problems with extremely high leverage in the high values of the DV: at a minimum you should check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple points:

1) Since your DV will be bounded by 0 and 1, it's likely that OLS regression will not be a good model. Beta regression might be good.

2) Instead of controlling for total vote, you could try controlling for date of review (and perhaps some measure of the popularity of the book being reviewed). Date of review will not be lumped. But that depends on the purpose of controlling for total vote.

3) I am generally opposed to categorizing variables. Here, however, you might try stratifying and running different analyses for the levels that you propose in your last comment.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'll keep those things in mind. One thing I want to ask is, I was planning to use Tobit regression, also called a censored regression model, because the variable is bounded in its range, as you pointed. But I do not know about Beta regression(I actually searched it, but I could not tell which regression model(between Tobit and Beta) is more suitable in this case..) Can you please tell me which one is better?

Comment: I am not sure which is better, frankly. Someone else here may know (lots and lots of knowledgeable people here)